# How to cite the web page address as the reference?

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I would like to cite a web page in the IEEE style. But I am not sure how to edit the bib code in the JabRef.

Comment: Please giv an example: which web page do you want to cite? How should the citation look in the document? BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 3):

I have at least six IEEE styles by default , but in any case you can use the type of reference  `@electronic` or may be  `@misc`. Probably you have in your disk the file  `IEEEexample.bib` with several entries like this:

```
@electronic{IEEEexample:IEEEwebsite,
  title         = "The {IEEE} Website",
  url           = "http://www.ieee.org/",
  year          = "2008",
  key           = "IEEE"
}
```

If this file exist, you can compile a file like the below MWE to test how these entries are formatted in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{IEEEexample:electronhowinfo,
      IEEEexample:electronhowinfo2,
      IEEEexample:electronorgadd,
      IEEEexample:hyperrefsty
      }
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEexample}
\end{document}
```

Of course, you must change `IEEEtran`  with the exact IEEE style that you are using.

[image: MWE]